# Union of interiors of convex sets

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

¿If A and B are convex sets, is it true that the union of their interiors is equal to the interior of their unions?

Comment: Look at two halves of a disk.

Comment: $A = (- \infty  , 0 ] $ and $B =[0  , + \infty)$

Answer (score 1):

*This question has been answered in the negative by the examples in the comments by @RedShoes, reproduced below.*

---

No, consider $A = (-\infty,0]$ and $B = [0,\infty)$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology.

Comment: It is advisable to replicate the important comments in your answer. One of the important purposes of giving such community wiki answers is to preserve the comments that give the answers, because (for example) comments can easily be lost.